# How to populate updated document by id in schema array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am  trying to learn and implement few operations which are newer for me. I have a child schema details which I am pushing in a parent schema array. Everything is going fine. But when it comes to front-end, concern about few things.

As per someone's advice ,I came to know we must store `_id` to another schema . And if we update details of that `_id`, it will get reflected in every schema docs where it has been stored.

Now I am login through parent schema and I want to see the entire details of those array  `_id` as I need to show lists in front-end. Right now I can only see `ids`. I want to populate array of entire object of those ids.

I can populate data but I need to use a different API Url to show list. I do not want that . I know if I change `ObjectId` to `Mixed`, I can see whole object. But problem is that it will not show updated data. So I am pushing by ObjectId `users:[ {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Userr'}]`

So how will I populated updated `users` aray data on my main schema array without creating new route api ??

**Child schema:-**

```
{
    "_id": "5d034653ff1e426fb0e3fca1",
    "firstName": "xyz",
    "lastName": "fg",
    "__v": 0
}
```

**Main schema response details :-**

```
{
    "admins": {
        "users": [
            "5d034653ff1e426fb0e3fca1" //<========= what i am getting 
        ],
        "email": "1cf1eede89@himail.online",
        "password": "$2a$10$vHyGxX9P.t0/ybKcmIzkc.ZCX18oHaVnvTgJIWA2gTNzJ3TCdXS4a",
    },
    "_id": "5d0339d5b4b28b6ddff06802",
    "companyID": "497399",
    "__v": 0
}
```

**I want to show result like this :**

```
{
    "admins": {
        "users": [
            "5d034653ff1e426fb0e3fca1",
            "firstName" : "xyz",
            "lastName" :"fg"
        ],
        "email": "1cf1eede89@himail.online",
        "password": "$2a$10$vHyGxX9P.t0/ybKcmIzkc.ZCX18oHaVnvTgJIWA2gTNzJ3TCdXS4a",
    },
    "_id": "5d0339d5b4b28b6ddff06802",
    "companyID": "497399",
    "__v": 0
}
```

**Function for registering user :-**

```
if(req.userData.role2 === 'admin') {
            console.log("saving successful");
            res.send(doc);
            Admin.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.userData.userId }, { $push: { 'admins.users': userr._id } }, { new: true })
            .populate('admins.users')
            .exec(function(error, res){
                    if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    }else {
                    console.log(res.admins.users+ "populated")
                    }
              });             
        }
```

This is showing me list of populate data but how can I show it in array object

*I need to show the updated object of child schema. So that I can use in front-end for listing whatever details I want*

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, what are you trying to populate, what are you trying to update? Can you please edit your question so that i can help you better.

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti Edited . I want to populate updated data of `users` array. As the `_id` over there is being pushed from the child schema. Also I can populate by creating a different api route but I want to show entire schema object with nested populated objects .

Comment: If you want to populate the users data just do `populate("admins.users")`.

Comment: @VirgilioGM I did , but on another api.  I want that if the respective id got edited on child doc, the updated child doc must populate in the array also. I don't want to query and edit same thing on both schema it will be complex for me

Comment: If you edit your question with your full update query I could help you better but you can just use the `populate` statement in it

Comment: @VirgilioGM edited my question. Please check

Comment: I don't see your update query (the one your are using now), just the output

Comment: @VirgilioGM Added  registration query. Please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194929/discussion-between-virgiliogm-and-noobcoder).